# Program doesn't proceed after reading input from console

Tags: ruby, input, console, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

In the code below, I used the `gets` method to read input from the console.

```
puts "Give me a number"
num = gets
puts "puts #{num.to_i * 2}"
```

Although it works and terminates on other environments, with Jetbrains RubyMine 2018.3.1 x64, the program doesn't proceed or terminate after reading the input I gave it. After I run the program, this appears on the console:

```
Give me a number
12
12
```

I have tried to uninstall and install it again, but the problem is not solved. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: It works on MRI. Something must be wrong with RubyMine, or your setting.

Comment: It works. Test on terminal. Maybe the IDE doesn't accept user input. Or check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147082/ruby-debugger-fails-on-stdin-gets-user-input

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted the support team of IntelliJ and this is a known issue. The link [1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-23100) describes exactly what I'm encountering. It will be fixed in RubyMine 2018.3.2 RC.